# How to change vector names of each list component

Tags: r

I have a list:

```
alist <- list(x = c(1, 2, 3),
              y = c(4, 5, 6))

> alist 
$x 
[1] 1 2 3
    
$y 
[1] 4 5 6
```

I want to give names to each list component, to make it become:

```
> alist 
$x 
t1 t2 t3
1  2  3
            
$y 
t1 t2 t3
4  5  6
```

I tried to use `lapply()`:

```
lapply(alist, function(x) names(x) <- c("t1","t2","t3"))
```

but the output is:

```
$x
[1] "t1" "t2" "t3"

$y
[1] "t1" "t2" "t3"
```

What is wrong here? How can I use lapply correctly here? Because I have a rather big list.

Comment: FYI, R (as in many languages) supports chain-assignment, e.g. `aa <- bb <- 5`. This is relevant because even an assignment operation like `names(x) <- c(..)`, it silently chains the value assigned, and functions/code-blocks "return" the last object in its space. The last value in that code-block is `names(x) <- c(..)`, where the value is chained along to be the value of that assignment; the "value" of that assignment is the value passed into it, which is `c("t1","t2","t3")`, not the whole vector `x`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option could be:

```
lapply(alist, setNames, c("t1","t2","t3"))

$x
t1 t2 t3 
 1  2  3 

$y
t1 t2 t3 
 4  5  6
```

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing wrong in the code except that the `return` should be the original data

```
lapply(alist, function(x) {
      names(x) <- c("t1","t2","t3");
       x})
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that, unless you include `return()` call at the end of the function, a function will return whatever the last result was. In your function as written, the last result was `names(x)`, which returns the vector names.

To fix that, be sure that your anonymous function returns the actual vector as the last result:

```r
alist <- list(x = c(1, 2, 3),
              y = c(4, 5, 6))

lapply(alist, function(x) {
  names(x) <- c("t1","t2","t3")
  x}
)
#> $x
#> t1 t2 t3 
#>  1  2  3 
#> 
#> $y
#> t1 t2 t3 
#>  4  5  6

# alternative:
lapply(alist, setNames, nm = c("t1","t2","t3"))
#> $x
#> t1 t2 t3 
#>  1  2  3 
#> 
#> $y
#> t1 t2 t3 
#>  4  5  6
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

In a very similar approach we could use `map` function from package `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)

alist %>%
  map(~ .x %>%
        set_names(c("t1", "t2", "t3")))

$x
t1 t2 t3 
 1  2  3 

$y
t1 t2 t3 
 4  5  6
```